# Whitelist IOS10 Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ios10, whitelist

I created a project before ios10 and it worked correctly.
Since the release of ios10, I have a problem with my application, only on ios.
My project is on ionic + cordova and i  make queries on a website like http://application.t-d.com/api.php and I retrieve a json object.
But, since ios10, i have this error message:

> Refused to load gap://ready because it appears in neither the child-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy.

So, i modified my config.xml and index.html, like indications on google searsh but none worked.

Actually in my config.xml

```
<content src="index.html"/>
<access origin='https://cordova.apache.org ' minimum-tls-version='TLSv1.1' requires-forward-secrecy='false' requires-certificate-transparency='true' />
<access origin='*' allows-arbitrary-loads-in-media='true' allows- arbitrary-loads-in-web-content='true' allows-local-networking='true' />
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="data:*"/>
```

and in my index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src gap://ready file://* *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline''unsafe-eval' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: zyour tag should be like: **<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src http: https: 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http: https:" />**

Comment: Please copy and paster my above tag in your **index.html** and remove yours, its' some typo in your tag.

Comment: Thanks Naitik for your answer. I try it

Comment: So, i keep my config.xml and i have modified my index.html. Now, in my safari console developpement, i have this when i lanch my app: deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. and Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady

Comment: Try to run code in deviceready function.

Comment: Works like a @Naitik! Your comment should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Glad to help you.. !!